Patch CMakeFile from another CmakeFile, is it possible?
I should apply a patch while running CMake in a CMakeFile.txt, e.g. like this scenario (image below).
Then my question; is it possible to patch a file CMakeFile2.txt from another file CMakeFile1.txt?
That is, after launch cmake options command line from shell, while cmake is reading the CMakeFile1.txt file, I want to modify (apply a patch) to the existing file CMakeFile2.txt.
If possible, how to do?
I have no idea!



Then my question; is it possible to patch a file CMakeFile2.txt from another file CMakeFile1.txt?

It's possible when using FetchContent or ExternalProject via the PATCH_COMMAND argument. You can also use execute_process prior to loading it to run a patch command on a local file.

However, you should avoid doing this at all costs. You have a few better options depending on what, exactly, you're trying to accomplish:

Use add_subdirectory and override the subproject's properties using set_property.
Use one of the many code injection features CMake provides.

What are you really trying to accomplish?
